# Azure Resource Manager - Get RDP certificate

Tags: azure

I'm trying to securely RDP to a new VM which I have created within the Resource Manager as suggested by the new portal.. However I cannot find the expected RDP certificate thumbprint to properly verify the connection.. Searching online I have come across `(Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $CloudServiceName -Name $Name | select -ExpandProperty vm).DefaultWinRMCertificateThumbprint` and `Get-AzureCertificate`, but this seems to only work for "classic" VMs. Is there an equivalent for the AzureRM* commandlets? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Click **Browse** > **Virtual machines** > **your Windows virtual machine** > **Settings**
2. You could see the **connect** button on top of the setting page, just click it and you could get your RDP certificate downloaded, then you could connect your Azure VM with it.

   [image]
3. If still not working, you could follow this link to [Troubleshoot Remote Desktop connections to an Azure virtual machine running Windows.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-troubleshoot-remote-desktop-connections#virtual-machines-created-using-resource-manager-deployment-model)

Comment: unfortunately the connect button only downloads the .rdp file which only has the ip address, and not the certificate

Comment: could you post the error message or the screenshot?

Comment: yes - https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D562FA99B29F700B!139&authkey=!AHtWPAjaVYYdKKM&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: Now that I've enough rep! This answer is correct. Your RDP connection does have the certificate and the connection will be secured, it is just not from a recognised CA. The error message is just a warning to let you know this. As you are connecting to your own VM, which has issued the certificate, you know where it came from so there is no danger.

Comment: @EdRixon I had a look inside .rdp files in notepad and unfortunately they don't have any certificate information